# Set struct var in a nested enum if fail to decode

Tags: swift

I have a simple struct that I need to set a flag on enum decode failure.  Not sure now to do that.

```
struct TestStruct: Codable {
  let testEnum: TestEnum

  let failDecode: Bool

}


extension TestStruct {

   enum TestEnum: String, Codable {

      case val1 = "VAL1"

      case val2 = "VAL2"
      public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
         let testState = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
         switch testState{
         case "VAL1": self = .val1
         case "VAL2": self = .val2
         default: TestStruct.failDecode = true   // fail compile here
         }
      }

   }

}
```

How do I set failDecode flag on decode failure?  Thxs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom `init(from:)` initializer for `TestStruct`. You do not need a custom `init(from:)` initializer for `TestEnum`.

```
struct TestStruct {
    let testEnum: TestEnum
    let failDecode: Bool
}

extension TestStruct {
    enum TestEnum: String, Codable {
        case val1 = "VAL1"
        case val2 = "VAL2"
    }
}

extension TestStruct: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            testEnum = try TestEnum(from: decoder)
            failDecode = false
        } catch {
            failDecode = true

            // You must initialize testEnum to some valid value,
            // even though you couldn't decode it!
            testEnum = .val1
        }
    }
}
```

If you want `Codable` conformance, not just `Decodable` conformance, then you also need to provide a matching `encode(to:)` method. Here's a simple implementation:

```
extension TestStruct: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try testEnum.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

(Note that `Codable` is an alias for `Decodable & Encodable`, so providing separate `Decodable` and `Encodable` conformances is the same as providing a single `Codable` conformance.)

I ignored the `failDecode` flag in that implementation of `encode(to:)`, but maybe you want to encode an illegal value if `failDecode` is set. This version encodes nil if `failDecode` is true:

```
extension TestStruct: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if failDecode {
            try Optional<TestEnum>.none.encode(to: encoder)
        } else {
            try testEnum.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.  This is what I needed.